# WPF Custom Property - required property

Tags: wpf, properties, custom-properties

Is there any way to make a custom property required in WPF?

I mean something like error message when my custom property in designer is not filled? E.g.: Required="true/false"

My custom property definition:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty AaFunctionalUnitNameProp;
    [Category(VsCategoryName.AaObjectInfo)]
    [Description(VsPropertyDescription.FunctionalUnitName)]
    public string AaFunctionalUnitName
    {
        get => (string)GetValue(AaFunctionalUnitNameProp);
        set => SetValue(AaFunctionalUnitNameProp, value);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no out-of-the-box feature that does this, however you could assign an *invalid* (by your definition) default value and in your `OnInitialized` event throw an exception when it's still the default value (Only when not in design-mode of course).

Example:

```
public class CustomControl : Control
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty RequiredPropertyProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "RequiredProperty", typeof(int), typeof(CustomControl), new PropertyMetadata(int.MinValue));

    public int RequiredProperty
    {
        get { return (int) GetValue(RequiredPropertyProperty); }
        set { SetValue(RequiredPropertyProperty, value); }
    }

    protected override void OnInitialized(EventArgs e)
    {
        if(RequiredProperty == int.MinValue)
            if(!DesignerProperties.GetIsInDesignMode(this))
                throw new Exception("RequiredProperty must be explicitly set!");

        base.OnInitialized(e);
    }
}
```